# Counting the number of instances of a month in a list of dates in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a large spreadsheet containing job information. I am trying to make a "Job Count by Month" field, and it doesn't pull correctly.

My Job Info is all located in a sheet called "3PL Jobs". I have a hidden sheet titled "Under The Hood" which contains a table of months next to their names (i.e. 'Under The Hood'!E2:E13 is a column of numbers and the F column has the corresponding "January","February", etc.

I've made a cell with a dropdown list of the months (pulling from the Under The Hood sheet) and in the cell directly to the right I want it to output the number of completed jobs.

I got this working with the dropdown month list being just a simple list of numbers and not the name, but it looks awful so I was hoping to use an index match to be able to use the name.

This is the code that worked with a list of month numbers, using I19 as the entry cell for the month number

```
=COUNTIFS(ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH('3PL Jobs'!C3:C)),I19,'3PL Jobs'!AR3:AR,"COMPLETE")
```

This is the code I've tried to include to index/match the month name (this in theory should just output the month number based on the name selected in I18, but it outputs "8" no matter what is selected)

`=arrayformula(index('Under The Hood'!E2:E13,MATCH(I18,'Under The Hood'!F2:F13),1))`

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but this is driving me nuts!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142U9tpuF7sAE-X7hKQNfK21Aw2Uh7VRRkIj6Y-jjTMg/edit?usp=sharing

The Cells in question are on Launch Page. J18 is currently just trying to get the corresponding number to the month chosen in I18. I19 is a manually-entered month number, and J19 is the (correct) count of jobs in the month entered in I19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to turn month name into month number all you need is:

```
=MONTH(I18&1)
```

Comment: This is great; the documentation for errors should mention this. I definitely tried `Month(I18)` and got the "There is no number here" error.